# Base directory path

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

Is there any way to get the base directory from a full path.
For example, I have /opt/mw/apache/etc 
And I need to get /opt
Is there any command to do it?

thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have to add a new question. I need to copy my script and get the base of the script directory.
For example /home/ui/mw_share/script/bin or /opt/mw/mw_share/script/bin. I need to get /*/*/mw_share.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below.

```
$ s='/opt/mw/apache/etc'
$ if [[ $s =~ ^(/[^/]*).* ]]; then echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}; fi
/opt
```

Answer (score 1):

Using awk:

```
echo '/opt/mw/apache/etc' | awk -F"/" '{print "/"$2}'
```

That will split the string by "/" then it will print "/" concatenated with the second token from the split, which is "opt".

Answer (score 1):

Just for grins, here's another way:

```
basedir() {
    dir=$1
    while [ $(dirname $dir) != "/" ]; do
        dir=$(dirname $dir)
    done
    echo $dir
}

> basedir /opt/mw/apache/etc
> /opt
```